# SQL Server 2008: Select returns multiple results instead of 1 per user in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my query, I want it to return my result set as Year = 2013, Month = 1 but for only one row per user for each month, with the hours logged in for the month totaled, I think the problem is with my grouping:

```
SELECT  YEAR(UP_Date) AS 'Year',
        MONTH(UP_Date) AS 'Month',
        SUM(ISNULL(UP_UserID,0)) AS UserID,
        U_UserName AS UserName,
        UP_AveCallTime AS AveCallTime,
        UP_TotCallTime AS TotCallTime,
        CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff) AS varchar) + ':' +
        CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR,UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff) AS varchar) + ':' +
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,UP_LogOn,UP_LogOff) AS varchar) AS [HoursOfMonth]

FROM [RPT_User_Performance_Data_cus]
INNER JOIN Users us ON
    UP_UserID = us.ID

GROUP BY Year(UP_Date), MONTH(UP_Date), UP_AveCallTime, UP_TotCallTime, U_UserName, UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff

------Result I Get----------------------------
Year    Month   UserID  UserName    AveCallTime TotCallTime HoursOfMonth
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL           0:0:4
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL           0:0:02
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL           0:3:21
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL           0:5:01
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL           NULL
2013    6   18553   KingGates   NULL               NULL           0:0:2
2013    6   18553   KingGates   NULL               NULL           0:1:31

-------Instead of ---------------------
Year    Month   UserID  UserName    AveCallTime TotCallTime HoursOfMonth
2013    6   18552   BossJobs    NULL               NULL            0:5:24
2013    6   18553   KingGates   NULL               NULL            0:1:33
```

Comment: A couple of problems here. First i can see you have 2 different UserId's for the same user (BossJobs) also, from what i can tell you are looking to sum the day, hour and min, is this the case? if so you cant sum a varchar they would need to be cast as INT. Also even if you sum the vaules it wouldn't add up to your expected output. please could you clarify these issues

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your query,

You group by things you don't want such as `UP_AveCallTime, UP_TotCallTime, U_UserName, UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff` , so remove them from the `group by`

for your `AveCallTime,TotCallTime,HoursOfMonth` you will want to use `SUM` or `AVG` depending on your logic

Comment: Hi, when I remove them I get this: Column 'RPT_User_Performance_Data_cus.UP_LogOff' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This error means you try to use a value you did not use in the group by without an aggregated function. Try to build your query in stages by removing all the aggregated parts at first and seeing you get what you want, than add them one by one to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  YEAR(UP_Date) AS 'Year',
        MONTH(UP_Date) AS 'Month',
        MAX(ISNULL(UP_UserID,0)) AS UserID,
        U_UserName AS UserName,
        AVG(UP_AveCallTime) AS AveCallTime,
        SUM(UP_TotCallTime) AS TotCallTime,
        CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff)) AS varchar) + ':' +
        CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,UP_LogOn, UP_LogOff)) AS varchar) + ':' +
        CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,UP_LogOn,UP_LogOff)) AS varchar) AS [HoursOfMonth]
FROM [RPT_User_Performance_Data_cus]
INNER JOIN Users us ON UP_UserID = us.ID
GROUP BY Year(UP_Date), MONTH(UP_Date), U_UserName
```

Not sure about your logic to get `[HoursOfMonth]`. You might need to tweak it or explain better.

Comment: I wanted to seperate the result of the total time logged in for the month as days:hours:munites, the problem is that my result set does not return summed up as shown in my query above.